# Query HTML file with LINQ

Tags: c#, html, linq

Does anyone know if there's a library that will allow you to Query the HTML DOM with LINQ?

Something like LINQtoHTML.

Would it be useful to create such a thing if it does not exist yet?

Comment: What kind of queries would you possibly want to issue?

Comment: find certain div tags or content in a HTML file.  Anything really...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) will let you do this.  It's pretty forgiving with malformed HTML, too.

Comment: If you get the new beta of HtmlAgilityPack it contains members very similar in style to LINQ-to-XML.  If you are already familiar with LINQ-to-XML this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently, however, if it's xhtml, you could load it up and use Linq-to-XML :)